# Perl code for reverse complement of DNA sequence

Tags: perl, reverse, dna-sequence, complement

I was trying to make a **perl** code to get the reverse complement of fasta sequences of DNA in a .fna file format.
the **sequence02C.fna** file contains 100s of DNA sequences :

```
>adbca3e
TGCTCCCCACGCTTGCCTCTCCAGTACTCAACCAAAGCAGTCTCTAGAAAAACAGTTTCCAACGCAATACGATGGAATTCCACTTCCCAAATATCTC
>4c2a958
TCCCCACGCTTTCGCGCTTCAGCGTCAGTATCTGTCCAGTGAGCTGACTTCTCCATCGGCATTCCTACACAGTACTCTAGAAAAACAGTTTCTGCTC
>0639b5b
TCGCGCCTCAGTGTCCAACGCAATACGAGTTGCAGACCAGGACACATGGAATTCCACTTCCCTCTCCAGTACTCAACCAAAGCAGTCTCTAGAAAAG
```

I have used the following command which can open the file and make reverse but does not show the sequence ID (eg: `>adbca3e`) in the output.

The code is:

```
#!/usr/local/perl

open (NS, "sequence02C.fna");
while (<NS>) {
    if ($_ =~ tr/ATGC/TACG/) {print $_;}
}
```

output file is only the complementary of the sequence but not reverse.
Additionally, it does not contain the sequence IDs ">adbca3e"

Could anyone please suggest the appropriate code to do this reverse complementary of this sequence at once and getting the result into an output file?

Comment: Maybe you should explain the difference between "complementary" and "reverse".

Comment: To print all lines, just remove the condition `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You only print the lines that contained a `A`, `T`, `G` or `C`. You want to print every line, so the print shouldn't be conditional.

```
#!/usr/local/perl

use strict;               # Always
use warnings;             # Always

while (<>) {
    if (/^>/) {           # Only modify lines starting with ">".
       tr/ATGC/TACG/;
       $_ = reverse($_);  # You didn't reverse.
    }

    print;                # Print undconditionally.
}
```

(`tr///` and `print` use `$_` by default.)

Note I didn't open the file. You can use the program as follows:

```sh
perl program.pl sequence02C.fna >sequence02C_revcomp.fna
```

or

```
perl -i~ program.pl sequence02C.fna
```

The latter modifies the file in place.  (Be careful! Test it first. It does make a backup, though.)

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a program to "make reverse", but it only gives complementary. Maybe that is a very obvious description for you, but it is not very clear to me.

If by "reverse" you mean to print the string backwards, just use the `reverse` function. Complementary I *assume* is taking the corresponding nucleobases, which is what your transliteration is meant to do `tr/ATGC/TACG/`.

To fix not printing ids, just remove the `if` condition on the print-statement.

What I would do is just use the diamond operator for a small program like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    unless (/^>/) {
        tr/ATGC/TACG/;            # transliterate non-ids
        my $reverse = reverse;    # reverse $_
        say $reverse;             # do something with $reverse
    }
    say;          # print current line
}
```

Then you can use this program like this:

```
$ perl program.pl sequence02C.fna > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @TLPfor the reply with codes.  I have used the following program, just with the open command adding to the suggested program : 
open (NS, "sequence02C.fna");

while (<NS>) {
    chomp;

 
but found error output: 
[siddiquee@intron2 realtask]$ perl rc.pl
syntax error at rc.pl line 13, near "my "
Global symbol "$reverse" requires explicit package name at rc.pl line 13.
Global symbol "$reverse" requires explicit package name at rc.pl line 14.
Execution of rc.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Global symbol .. is when you do not declare a variable using `my`. In your case, sounds like you missed ending a line with semi-colon, so that `my` got corrupted. The error is not visible in the code you show in the comment however.

Comment: @mashuk There was actually a semi-colon missing in my code, added it now.